# How can I apply memoization to this recursive function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was solving the Subset Sum problem: "Given a set of numbers, check whether it can be partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of elements in both subsets is same or not." For this problem I created a recursive function which works correctly but I am not able to correctly memoize it.

The code is:

```
bool func(int a[], int i, int n, long sum) // i is 0, n is the array size, sum is required sum
{

    if(sum<0||i>=n)
      return 0;
    if(sum==0)
      return 1;

    if(func(a,i+1,n,sum-a[i]))
      return 1;
    if(func(a,i+1,n,sum))
      return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Please help in memoizing this code. Also can you tell that which is better for these type of problems recursive code with memoization or tabulation.

Comment: Aside: `true` and `false` are `bool` literals, `1` and `0` are `int`s

Comment: Hint: `a` and `n` are constants in your recursion, `i` and `sum` are variables. So you need a 2d-array for all possible values of `i` (`[0, n)`) and all possible values of sum (`[0, sum]`). I personally think that memoization makes the algorithm easier to understand  - given that you have a ready-made memoization library. If not, tabulation would probably be easier to implement.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele can you please tell what is ready-made memoization library

Comment: It would be something with a function (template) `func_t memoise(func_t);`, given `using func_t = std::function<bool(int*, int, int, long)>;`

Comment: Aside 2: I think your function is incorrect, the second recursive call should have `sum+a[i]`, and the checks at the front should be `if (i == n) return sum == 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabulation is much easier.

```
bool ss(int a[],int n,int s){
  bool r[n+1][s+1];
  for(int i=0;i<=n;++i)
     r[i][0]=true;
  for(int i=1;i<=s;++i)
     r[0][s]=false;
  for(int i=1;i<=n;++i)
    for(int j=1;j<=s;++j)
      if(j>=a[i])
       r[i][j]=r[i-1][j] || r[i-1][j-a[i]];
      else r[i][j]=r[i-1][j];
  return r[n][s];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Memoization just means storing already-computed results so you don't have to recompute them later. So, whenever `func` calls itself and gets an answer, add an entry to a dictionary that maps `func`'s inputs to its output. Then, before calling func, see if there's already an entry in the dictionary for the inputs you're about to use and, if so, don't call `func` again; instead, use the output you cached in the dictionary.